# I want to calculate the distance between two points using network analysis

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
    function drawroute(allcordinate) {
        var Coordinate = new Array();
        Coordinate = allcordinate;
        var long = Coordinate.split(",")[0];
        var lat = Coordinate.split(",")[1];
        var long1 = Coordinate.split(",")[2];
        var lat1 = Coordinate.split(",")[3];
        routeTask = new esri.tasks.RouteTask("http://111.93.174.107:6080/arcgis/rest/services/network/KendraparaNetwork/NAServer/Route");
        //set up the route parameters
        routeParams = new esri.tasks.RouteParameters();
        routeParams.stops = new esri.tasks.FeatureSet();
        routeParams.outSpatialReference = { "wkid": 102100 };
        dojo.connect(routeTask, "onSolveComplete", showRoute);
        dojo.connect(routeTask, "onError", errorHandler);
        //define the symbology used to display the route
        stopSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CROSS).setSize(15);
        stopSymbol.outline.setWidth(4);
        routeSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([246, 26, 26, 0.7])).setWidth(5);
        var stop;
        var start = new esri.geometry.Point(lat, long, new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
        var end = new esri.geometry.Point(lat1, long1, new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                stop = map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(start, stopSymbol));
                routeParams.stops.features.push(stop);
            }
            else {
                stop = map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(end, stopSymbol));
                routeParams.stops.features.push(stop);
            }
        }
        if (routeParams.stops.features.length >= 2) {

            routeTask.solve(routeParams);
            lastStop = routeParams.stops.features.splice(0, 1)[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: and? ... is there a question here? ... or an error returned from using this code?

Comment: I am using this code to pass two dynamic points lat and long to and it will solve the query and provide me the route present in feature layer, Please kindly help me to solve the distance covered by the two points and dynamically bind it to front side, I am not able to get using geometry services

Comment: This is the total solution ,The Function will take the Long and lat from the back end in string format then it will split the lat and long into individual variable pass the variable to route parameters to solve the network

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawroute(drawroute) {
                var Coordinate = new Array();
                Coordinate = drawroute;
                var long = Coordinate.split(",")[0];
                var lat = Coordinate.split(",")[1];
                var long1 = Coordinate.split(",")[2];
                var lat1 = Coordinate.split(",")[3];
                routeTask = new RouteTask("http://111.93.174.107:6080/arcgis/rest/services/network/KendraparaNetwork/NAServer/Route");
                routeParams = new RouteParameters();
                routeParams.stops = new FeatureSet();
                routeParams.outSpatialReference = { "wkid": 102100 };
                routeTask.on("solve-complete", showRoute);
                routeTask.on("error", errorHandler);
                // stopSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SOLID).setSize(15);

                //           var stopSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 10, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([89, 95, 35]), 2),
                //          new Color([130, 159, 83, 0.40]));

                stopSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CROSS).setSize(15);
                stopSymbol.outline.setWidth(4);
                routeSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([233, 30, 99, 1])).setWidth(5);
                var start = new Point(lat, long, new SpatialReference({ "wkid": 4326 }));
                var end = new Point(lat1, long1, new SpatialReference({ "wkid": 4326 }));

                //var start = new Extent(lat, long, new SpatialReference({ "wkid": 4326 })); 
                //var end = new Extent(lat1, long1, new SpatialReference({ "wkid": 4326 }));
                for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        stop = map.graphics.add(new Graphic(start, stopSymbol));
                        routeParams.stops.features.push(stop);

                    }
                    else {
                        stop = map.graphics.add(new Graphic(end, stopSymbol));
                        routeParams.stops.features.push(stop);
                    }
                }


                if (routeParams.stops.features.length >= 2) {
                    routeTask.solve(routeParams);
                    lastStop = routeParams.stops.features.splice(0, 1)[0];
                }
            } window.drawroute = drawroute;
            var mapOnLoad = map.on("load", drawroute);
```

Comment: The last two lines are very important,It may not put your map, you might get an error in console that the map.graphics.add can not be added,so when the page is loaded then after the network analysis will work